# How to get the order_id from an observer

Tags: orders, event-observer, social-buttons

I tried to get the `order_id` from an observer

here is my observer

```
 public function adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore($observer) {
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
            var_dump($this->getOrderId());
            $block->addButton('do_something_crazy', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Sticker'),
                    'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getPrintStickerUrl() . '\')',
                    'class'     => 'go'
            ));           
        }
    }
```

I got this error:

Call to undefined method `Company_extention_Model_Observer::getOrderId()`.
I tried too `$order = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();`

but nothing,

Could you help me?

thanks

Comment: Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id') try this you will get order id

Answer (score 3):

The `$observer` variable contains all the information and methods you need. You were on the right track with `$observer->getEvent()`, but from there you must figure out what variables are stored in the event and access them appropriately.

A quick grep shows that the event is triggered in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container with the line: `Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_widget_container_html_before', array('block' => $this));`, so you can access that variable with `getBlock()`. Now after checking that the block type is the one you want, you can call `getOrder()` on the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View object.

Your method should look something like this:

```
public function adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore($observer) {
  $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
  if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
    $order = $block->getOrder();
    $block->addButton('do_something_crazy', array('label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Sticker'), 'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getPrintStickerUrl() . '\')', 'class' => 'go'));
  }
}
```

Comment: hi Nachito, Thanks for your help but, unfortunatly, it is not work. var_dump($observer->getEvent()->getOrder()); give me NULL.

Comment: What event are you observing?

Comment: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View, I'm trying to add a button,

Comment: @ismo: Updated.

Comment: Thanks against, I can load the object order. and now how to get the order_id?

Comment: Hi, I get the id by $order->getId(); Thank you againt.

Answer (score 0):

It can better idea to `use class match` and

### Issue: wrong object:

`$this` mean current  class object  and  but you need `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View` class  object .As per `$block` is object of this `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View`.

`$this->getOrderId()` should be `$block->getOrdeId()`;

The function   `getOrderId()` is exits in that class but it is  given  null value henever this does not have value.

for getting Sale model object then  try this
 $`block=$block->getOrder()`;

Then you can use

```
get_class($block)==Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View
```

**instead of**

```
$block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View
```